# Is there any way to hide the title bar of a program using AutoHotKey in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey

I wrote an AHK script to run a game (Space Empires V) in "fullscreen windowed" mode that does not support that mode, because it runs at a faster FPS in windowed mode for some reason, but I like the fullscreen experience. The way I do this is basically to run the game in windowed mode, but at the resolution of my screen, then use AHK to mask out the title bar. (I tried setting the form border style to just not have a title bar, but that seemed to break the game's rendering code, at least in Windows 7.)

My problem is that my script works just fine in Windows 7 and in the Windows 8 Release Preview, but in the final release of Windows 8, Windows refuses to actually hide the title bar. Does anyone know of a way to work around this issue?

You can download my script here:

http://spaceempires.net/downloads-file-920.html

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly better suited to StackOverflow?

Comment: @Karan Hmm... I'm not sure with this one. Possibly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized I didn't even need to remove the title bar in my script! All I needed to do was to move the window so the title bar was offscreen, which I was doing already. So commenting out the line that tries to remove the title bar solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to hide the borders completely I always use this:

```
WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
```

Or if you want a border around it you could do:

```
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
```

Combined with a shortcut works quite nice, for example:

```
!^f::
WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
WinMove, A, , 0, 0, 1680, 1050
return
```

This way you'd open your game in windowed mode and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to make it *fullscreen*.

Enjoy ;).

EDIT: Remember to change 1680 and 1050 to your actual resolution which from your script would be 1600x900.

Comment: Thanks, but this just makes the game window completely gray - I guess it breaks DirectX or something!

Comment: That's odd, I've used it with different kind of programs and some old games to accomplish the same you wanted. But it's good to know you got it working anyway.

Comment: @Xandy how do you revert o original settings of the Window after this?